# One JSON file is processed; an identical copy is not

Tags: javascript, json

We use the [D3 JavaScript](http://d3js.org/) to initialize data documents, then build an application-specific `JavaScript` to process data.

A subset of the application-specific `JavaScript` looks like this:

```
   drawLegend();
   thousand_sep_format = d3.format(',');
   d3.json("http://wafi.iit.cnr.it/webvis/tmp/dbpedia/realOntology.json", function(error, root)
```

More specifically it correctly processes this `JSON` file:

```
   http://wafi.iit.cnr.it/webvis/tmp/dbpedia/realOntology.json
```

However, when we copy the *original* `JSON` file to another `Linux/Ubuntu` server, the copied `JSON` file cannot be processed.

Here is the *copied* JSON file:

```
   http://www.ontomatica.com/public/test/dbpedia_ontology/realOntology.json
```

What is the difference between `JSON`-*original* and `JSON`-*copied*?

What is the correct process to copy an original `JSON` file to a new server?

Our goal is to remove sections of the original `JSON` file and then `plot` the subset. Therefore we have to put a working subset on a server.

Comment: Check console and network tabs. Scientific guess: same origin policy

Comment: Based on glancing at the response headers from the two URLs and making the assumption that `d3` indicates that the code is running in a browser, then the answer will be found in the browser's developer tools' console and is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).

Comment: @zerkms Could you give me a bit more information to follow - not sure what to look at. Further, we need the JS to read the URL and don't see a difference between the two URLs.

Comment: @JayGray — The phrase [same origin policy](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=same+origin+policy&ia=about) is plenty of information to follow (as is the mention of the console which gives a pretty detailed error message for this in most browsers).

Comment: "a bit more information to follow" 1. Check console and network tabs 2. Put the "same origin policy" into google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first site responds with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with the value `*`. That tells browsers that they should allow xhr access to the site regardless of the originating domain.

The other site doesn't do that, so the browser won't fetch the content.

The problem has nothing to do with the URLs as such, nor with the JSON content. It's a matter of server configuration, and exactly how you change that depends on the hosting environment.

Comment: ^This is likely the correct answer.
Another difference that might cause issues is that www.ontomatica.com sends the content-type as 'text/plain' instead of 'application/json'.